# Can a diplexer connect two antennas with 2.4GHz signal to one transceiver?

Tags: bluetooth, radio, wifi

I'm looking at using a single transceiver to handle multiple 2.4GHz signals.  Think like 2.4GHz mouse or game controller.

A diplexer can easily take two antennae and plug them into one RF signal port on an RF Microprocessor, which can then split out the 2.4GHz and 5GHz signals.  What about 2.4GHz signals in different channels, e.g. 2.4GHz Wifi and 2.4GHz mouse from two antennae going to the diplexer?  Would that be infeasible due to proximity of the frequencies?

Comment: You should include a drawing (block schematic) of your proposal as it is unclear to me what you're actually proposing. The 2.4 GHz signals will need to fall within the 2.4 GHz ISM band which is quite small, meaning the frequency difference is too small for a diplexer to separate one signal from the other. The devices might actually be using the same or very similar frequencies. Example: Bluetooth and WiFi (at 2.4 GHz) also use the same ISM frequency band.

Comment: As @Bimpelrekkie says, if they are both on the 2.4Ghz band, then a single antenna is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diplexer combines or splits significantly different frequencies. 'Significantly' means far enough apart so that they can be separated by a filter. Where the two filters join, each is high impedance at the other's centre frequency, so they don't load the other signal. If you can build the filters, you can make a diplexer. If you can't, then you get a signal combiner/splitter, with at best 3dB loss.

All nominally 2.4GHz ISM band signals, mice, WiFi, bluetooth, are essentially the same band. It's not even possible to specify a filter to split them, let alone realise one in hardware.

2.4GHz and 5GHz is a relatively easy split. I've been peripherally involved with diplexers that split 1800 from 1900 MHz mobile comms bands, and they used some quite expensive engineering to the get the Q and stability required.

There are several ways to approach a signal combiner design. At these frequencies, the most practical would be a [Wilkinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_power_divider) combiner, using microstrip on PCB.

Comment: I've seen band-pass filters that narrowly pass the 2.4GHz Wifi channel 6, but that's more of a noise filtering tool. Your explanation makes sense.